# Is there any pre-requisits as a sender to use promotab?

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
[{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "logo": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png"
},{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "subjectLine": "[Important] Please add subject line in annotation"
},{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "DiscountOffer",
  "description": "20% off",

  "discountCode": "PROMO",
  "availabilityStarts": "2021-04-07T09:19:24-07:00",
  "availabilityEnds": "2021-04-10T09:19:24-07:00"
},{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "PromotionCard",
  "image": "https://www.google.com/gmail-for-marketers/promo-tab/markup-tool/sample.png"
}]
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(243, 242, 240); cursor: auto;">
<center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;background-color:#f3f2f0;">
<table bgcolor="#f3f2f0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f3f2f0;" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="100%">
   <div class="webkit" style="max-width:600px;Margin:0 auto;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>

      <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0" >
       <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
        <![endif]--><!-- ======= start main body ======= -->
   <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="outer" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><!-- ======= start header ======= -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <center>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin: 0 auto;" width="100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="one-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><!-- ======= start header ======= -->
               <table bgcolor="#f3f2f0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:left;font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="20%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:30px;" >
             <![endif]-->
                  <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:80px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                  <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td align="left" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:5px;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img align="left" alt="" height="60" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/dbe9c57f-5e00-4d9f-9719-5d36a9a02ebc.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:60px;height:auto; display:block" width="60" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="80%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->

                  <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:518px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
                      <tbody>
                       <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="top"><img alt="" height="16" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/c01afe22-e370-4df3-b96e-927714713f51.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:20px;height:auto; max-height:16px; padding-top:0px; padding-left:10px" width="20" /><font style="font-size:11px; text-decoration:none; color:#474b53; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:16px; padding-bottom:30px"><a href="#" style="color:#474b53; text-decoration:none" target="_blank">View as a web page</a></font></td>
                       </tr>
                      </tbody>
                     </table>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]--></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- ======= end header ======= --><!-- ======= start two column ======= -->

      <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" border-left:1px solid #e8e7e5; border-right:1px solid #e8e7e5" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" background="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/595fac04-56a2-46f4-982e-69600273e5d0.jpg" bgcolor="#1f3ca6" class="two-column" height="260" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0" valign="top" width="600"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:260px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/595fac04-56a2-46f4-982e-69600273e5d0.jpg" color="#1f3ca6" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
         <div><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->
         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="inner" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;">
            <table class="contents1" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:30px" valign="middle">
               <p style="font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>

               <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px">Consectetur hi $name$ elitsed do eiusmod tempor sitabore et dolore magna aliqua.<br />
               <br />
               <a href="#" style="color:#1f3ca6; text-decoration:none" target="_blank"><strong>Read more &raquo;</strong></a></p>

               <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40" style="-moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; border-radius:10px;" width="120"><a class="button_link" href="#" style="width:120; display:block; text-decoration:none; border:0; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-size:13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #1f3ca6">Read more &raquo; </a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->

         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/fc68f7b7-efa6-45db-8b6f-ac6f78ae6782.png" style="border-width:0;width:100%; height:auto;" width="290" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]--></div>
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- ======= end two column ======= --><!-- ======= start two column ======= -->

      <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->
         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left"><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/c11788a0-0366-43bd-812f-4756c82a6f93.jpg" style="border-width:0;width:100%; height:auto;display:block" width="300" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->

         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:20px;padding-left:30px;">
            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:30px" valign="middle">
               <p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:none; color:#262626; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left"><strong>lorem ipsum</strong></p>

               <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#3a3d41; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px">Lorem ipsum dolor lorem cupidat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit telaborum.<br />
               &nbsp;</p>

               <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td align="center" bgcolor="#1f3ca6" height="40" style="-moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; border-radius:10px;" width="120"><a class="button_link" href="#" style="width:120; display:block; text-decoration:none; border:0; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-size:13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff">Read more &raquo; </a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>

               <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#3a3d41; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px"></p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- ======= end two column ======= --><!-- ======= start two column ======= -->

      <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->
         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:20px;padding-left:30px;">
            <table class="contents1" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:30px" valign="middle">
               <p style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:none; color:#262626; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left"><strong>lorem ipsum</strong></p>

               <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#3a3d41; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px">Lorem ipsum dolor lorem cupidat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit telaborum.<br />
               &nbsp;</p>

               <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="Margin:0 auto;">
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td align="center" bgcolor="#1f3ca6" height="40" style="-moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; border-radius:10px;" width="120"><a class="button_link" href="#" style="width:120; display:block; text-decoration:none; border:0; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;font-size:13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff">Read more &raquo; </a></td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>

               <p style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none; color:#3a3d41; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; text-align:left; line-height:18px"></p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->

         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/4dccd1e6-3ce2-4fd9-9b94-635e70bb09e2.jpg" style="border-width:0;width:100%; height:auto; display:block" width="300" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- ======= end two column ======= --><!-- ======= start two column ======= -->

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" background="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/595fac04-56a2-46f4-982e-69600273e5d0.jpg" bgcolor="#1f3ca6" class="two-column" height="200" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0" valign="top" width="600"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:200px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/595fac04-56a2-46f4-982e-69600273e5d0.jpg" color="#1f3ca6" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
         <div><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->
         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="inner" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:10px;padding-left:30px;">
            <table class="contents1" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:30px" valign="middle">
               <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size:25px; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; line-height:22px ; text-transform:uppercase">lorem ipsum</p>

               <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size:60px; text-align:center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">40%</p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->

         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:299px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><img alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/934e8df4-ef47-4dc5-b8e3-a1ccab54963d.png" style="border-width:0;width:100%; height:auto;" width="282" /></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]--></div>
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- ======= end two column ======= --><!-- ======= start footer ======= -->

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td class="two-column" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" >
             <tr>
             <td width="60%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
             <![endif]-->
         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:350px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="right" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:10px;padding-left:0;" width="39%"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" height="59" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/13f425ab-c680-4ae0-88de-7b493d95095f.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:59px;height:auto; display:block; padding-right:20px" width="59" /></a></td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" valign="middle" width="61%">
            <p style="color:#787777; font-size:13px; text-align:left; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Lorem ipsum &copy; 2017<br />
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum<br />
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
             </td><td width="40%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >         <![endif]-->

         <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:248px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
         <table style="border-spacing:0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:10px; padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="center" style="padding-top:10px" valign="top" width="32%">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="150">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="33"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="facebook" border="0" height="36" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/1f9161ee-46b5-4bdf-86db-9e32d4b98336.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:36px;height:auto; display:block; max-height:36px" width="36" /></a></td>
                  <td align="center" width="34"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="twitter" border="0" height="36" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/4e449140-ec71-4978-97bf-8e0f15b5ff23.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:36px;height:auto; display:block; max-height:36px" width="36" /></a></td>
                  <td align="center" width="33"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="linkedin" border="0" height="36" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/fdcaf86ecc5056741eb5cbc18/images/d21cca91-335e-4fa4-9313-b0ea37e0452b.jpg" style="border-width:0; max-width:36px;height:auto; display:block; max-height:36px" width="36" /></a></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>  </td>            </tr> </table>          <![endif]--></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td height="30" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:20px;"><span style="color: rgb(39, 65, 107); font-family: engagefont, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Calibri Light&quot;, Roboto, sans-serif, &quot;Microsoft YaHei&quot;, 微软雅黑, STXihei, 华文细黑, &quot;ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3&quot;, &quot;Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro&quot;, Osaka, メイリオ, Meiryo, &quot;ＭＳ Ｐゴシック&quot;, &quot;MS PGothic&quot;, &quot;Malgun Gothic&quot;; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">$unsub$</span></span></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>

   <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="outer" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><span style="font-size:20px;"><!-- ======= end footer ======= --></span></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <![endif]--></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working for an emailing platform and I've been asked by a customer if we enabled Google Promotab in email designs.
I have read the documentation, tried to do a test yet I couldn't manage to display the promotion. My Gmail account is not ending with "promotabtesting@gmail" but it is configured as expected on troubleshooting section.

- Are there any pre-requisits as a sender to enable the promotab feature?
  I ask for both our clients (Brands) and my company that doesn't figure on "they support promotab" here : https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview but could be very soon.

Thanks a lot for your help
Max
Project Manager

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: apparently the comment section is too short to let me copy/paste the <script type="application/ld+json"> I put into the <head> of my email design.

Comment: It is pretty basic, i've took it from https://freshinbox.com/tools/gmailpromotab/ using the ld json version.
The receiver is my gmail mailbox; the sender is a regular one - no BIMI or specific configuration other than regulars for emailing.
Are there any other information you'd like to get to understand?

Comment: Try editing your question to add the missing code

Comment: here it is, a test html design including the ld json version of the script.

Comment: But does the markup show up in your recipient email? Or it doesn't. I understand you want your email to end up in the promotions tab, right?

Comment: Exactly, I want it to but no markups show up. That's my issue. I wonder if it is due to the sender that must be approved by Google in a first hand or if my design is the issue.

Comment: I tested your code and it is working. The HTML is received. I believe you have to use the email ending in promotiontabtesting@gmail.com